# How to calculate plus two large number correctly in R

Tags: r, math

I have a stupid question.
I have a problem calculating a very simple plus thing in R.
When I try as below, it shows a strange result.
Could you let me know why?

```r
> format(14429588100216510 + 8918402888002604, scientific = F)
[1] "23347990988219112"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a big integer number (> 4 bytes).  We could use a package that supports those integers

```
library(gmp)
add.bigz(14429588100216510, 8918402888002604)
#Big Integer ('bigz') :
#[1] 23347990988219114
```

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your answer. :)